# How to call same request in a loop in gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

Background:
I want to perform a test where I need to check time taken to transfer data from one api to another api.
for ex:

1. /API_1 is sending data
2. /API_2 gets the data from API_1. here not all data is received at once it is coming in chunks and taking time.
   So i want to record this delay.

I am trying this

```
 val ExeScn= scenario("CheckDelay")
         .exec(http("XX-Post")
          .post("src/v1/req")
          .header("Authorization", "ABCD")
          .body(StringBody(postBody))
          .asJSON
      .check(jsonPath("$.data.name[*].address[*].property").findAll.is("Completed")
       )
```

How do I apply a loop here?

I want to run scenario("CheckDelay") till below condition

.check(jsonPath("$.data.name.address.property").find.is("Completed")

Answer (score 0):

- loop: [`asAlongAs`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/scenario/#aslongas)
- condition for the loop: : [`isUndefined()`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/expression_el/#expression-language)
- check: simple find with a [`notExists`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/check/#validating)

Comment: I am new to gatling and scala I tried to add aslongas loop but its going into indefinite loop. could you please add a sample code.